# How to define a variable in Postgres query and hold value?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a Postgres database and I have the below sample table.

[image]

I have a function that runs a period of time and every time it runs, select some rows with query and send it to Azure service bus.
I wanna define a variable in the query and hold the last value like "id". Next time to run select data from the last value.

For example:

First run: select rows with id "1" and "2"

Second run: select rows with id "3" and "4"

My code is:

```
import os
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage


conndb = psycopg2.connect(
    database="testDB", user="postgres", password="***", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432"
)
connstr = "****"
queue_name = '****'


data = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM cricketers
                         ORDER BY id
                         OFFSET 0 ROWS
                         FETCH FIRST 2 ROW ONLY''', conndb)
data_send = data.to_string()

with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connstr) as client:
    with client.get_queue_sender(queue_name) as sender:
        single_message = ServiceBusMessage(data_send)
        sender.send_messages(single_message)
```

I'm thinking of using a variable on `OFFSET variable ROWS`

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to use `sequence` :

```sql
create sequence cricketersSeq
as int 
increment by 2 
minvalue 0
owned by cricketers.id
```

`owned by` just associates sequence with the table and has nothing to do with the sequence of the it. sequence is set or increased by setval() and nextval()

and change your query to this :

```
select *
from cricketers
order by id 
offset nextval('cricketersSeq') rows 
fetch first 2 row only
```

be aware that the sequence keep track of row number and not id column.and since you've used offset fetch , I assume that's what you want.

but you can adjust the sequence to keep track of id instead of row number:

```sql
create sequence cricketersSeq
as int 
minvalue 0
owned by cricketers.id
```

and your query will be like this:

```
select setval('cricketersSeq',id) , * 
from cricketers
where id >(select last_value from cricketersSeq)
order by id 
limit 2;
```

Comment: I want to keep track of the last row I fetched on the query. Next time I will start after that row. For example, the first query starts from 0 to 100 and the next time query is 101 to 200.

Comment: @Shadi then checkout second solution.